# windows service application installation

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I am beginner to .NET.

I have a question regarding windows service application running multi-thread. My question is when I tried to register my application into windows service, I see my service status in "starting" in the service windows. I have included few lines code to show what I am trying to do.

```
protected override void OnStart(string [] args) {
    timer = Timer(5000);
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime); 
    timer.Start();

    // when I commented out Application.Run() it runs perfect.
    Application.Run(); // run until all the threads finished working
    //todo
}

private void OnElapsedTime(object s, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
    SmartThreadPool smartThreadPool = new SmartThreadPool();

    while( i < numOfRecords){
         smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(DoWork);
         //.....
    }
}
```

If you need further information please let me know.

Comment: What would you say `Application.Run()` is expected to do in the context you've provided?

Comment: Thanks for reviewing my code. I am sorry I forgot to put the loop before smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(DoWork). However I am trying to wait for all the running threads before the main program exit. I hope you understand what I am trying to do. Let me change the code for you.

Comment: For the service to show "started" OnStart must be allowed to finish.  There are other entry points (OnStop, etc.) for later state changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Run()` in the context you've used it just tells the service to run itself again in the same application context. As a part of your Windows Service, an application context already exists within the context of your `ServiceBase`. Since it's a service, it won't stop until it's given an instruction to stop through either a method that requires it, an unhandled exception or an external command.

If you're concerned about preventing the stop from occurring while threads are in the midst of executing, you'll need a global lock of some sort indicating processes are working. It might be as simple as elevating the scope of your `SmartThreadPool`:

```
private SmartThreadPool _pool = null;
private SmartThreadPool Pool 
{
    get
    {
        if (_pool == null)
            _pool = new SmartThreadPool();
        return _pool;
    }
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
   if (Pool != null)
   {
       // Forces all threads to finish and 
       // achieve an idle state before 
       // shutting down
       Pool.WaitForIdle();
       Pool.Shutdown();
   }
}
```

Comment: It is exactly what I am looking for.Thanks. Let me ask you one question before ending this topic. Is there any other way not using the WaitForIdle or waitforany method.

Comment: @Lakhae: I didn't look too deeply into the SmartThreadPool class (I'm assuming you're using the one from CodeProject), but I did see a method in there that looked like it would force a graceful shutdown. I don't recall what it was though.